# save_post_{CPT} not updating the 'sticky_posts' option

Tags: options, save-post, sticky-post

```
add_action( "save_post_{CPT}", 'update_sticky', 15, 1 );
function update_sticky( $post_id ) {

    $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    if ( ! in_array( $post_id, $stickies ) ) {
        $stickies[] = $post_id;
        update_option( 'test', $stickies);
        update_option( 'sticky_posts', $stickies );
    }
}
```

- It **does** work for `test` option I created for testing, but **it doesn't** work for existing `sticky_posts` option, although everything is the same.
- It does work for both if I hardcode the $post_id, like: `$stickies[] = 123;`
- Tried it in `functions.php` file, as well as in the class in which I am registering the CPT, same results - `test` is working, while `sticky_posts` is not.
- Tried different action priorities, 5, 10, 15, 99

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what you're are experiencing is that within the [`edit_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_post/) the updated post is [automatically removed](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/e1b417f5dc17dcdf45ac56ecf1a9e5cdd26039aa/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L446) from the sticky posts. This happens for users that can publish posts and edit others post's, after the post is updated and the `save_post` hooks have fired.

Note that core uses helper functions like `stick_post()`, `unstick_post()` and `is_sticky()` to do this kind of task.

As far as I understand the sticky posts feature is only fully implemented for the the built-in post type. So I'm not sure it's a good idea to mix it with other custom post types.